# Tv drama, nuclear bunker 1960s

Tags: story-identification

This was a B&W SF drama or film I watched on UK TV way back in the mid sixties. Very vague memories.

Some military people in a bunker and alerts go off, two men rush to man their stations, one says something like "Ready to alert Control?" and his colleague repeats back that he's ready...they then do the sequence of switches and simultaneous turning of keys "3,2,1" and they press a big button each. Then one sits sobbing.

Lots of dialogue with science jargon (I was only about 8 or 9 so it didn't make much sense)
Then there was a scene were they talked on a TV screen to people in rags in a blasted townscape...lots of speech about what "you people down in the caves have done to us".

Eventually the contamination seeps in and people get sort of paralysed and die.
Some of them keep running down sets of stairs to the floor below but it follows them floor by floor and they're like frozen in paralysis.

One guy is left and is standing all trembling awaiting his doom.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sounds like *[Level 7](https://archivetvmusings.blog/2014/12/03/out-of-the-unknown-level-seven/)*, an episode of *[Out Of The Unknown](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058836/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3a)*   Based on [the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_7_(novel)) by  Mordecai Roshwald. Broadcast 1966.

While much of OOTU is missing, this episode fortunately survives.

> Level Seven is 4,500 feet beneath the Earth’s surface and it’s designed to be the last line of attack in the event of a nuclear war.  Above them are six other levels – the first four are for civilians, the fifth is for the Government, scientists and the military whilst the sixth houses Defence Command.
>
> X127 (Keith Buckley) is one of a select number of operatives charged with pushing the buttons that will release the missiles of death and destruction on the enemy.  X117 (David Collings) works alongside him, but questions the reason for Level Seven’s existence.  Whilst X117 runs foul of the authorities, X127 has met and married R747 (Michele Dotrice).
>
> Eventually the order to attack is given and X127 and the new X117 (Sean Arnold) fire every last missile.  The General (Anthony Bate) tells them that the war is over and they’ve won – but what price victory?  Slowly it becomes apparent that everybody in the world is dead or dying and whilst it was predicted that Level Seven would be immune, that isn’t the case.  There is no hope at all, so all they can do is to wait for the inevitable end.

I've seen it, a few years ago. It definitely had the plot of the radiation descending level by level, eventually killing everyone.  I don't recall if they were paralyzed, as such.

Comment: I believe you are right. Here a couple of subtitle lines of Level Seven:

[00:32:51,007 --> 00:32:52,565]
Ready to alert control.

[00:32:52,807 --> 00:32:54,286]
Ready to alert control.

[00:41:32,447 --> 00:41:37,441]
We know we're dying,
it's hard to speak at all.

[00:41:37,567 --> 00:41:39,842]
So listen to us, you people down
there in the caves.

[00:41:39,967 --> 00:41:42,083]
There's nothing to see here,